# Windows Mobile - RFID Reader - IP 30

Tags: rfid, windows-mobile-6

Hello Guys i'm getting this error below, when i tried to connect the RFID in my Windows Mobile Application.

```
System.MissingMethodException: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'rfidapi32.dll'.
```

There is any Solution?

I find rfidapi32.dll on web and added to my .exe folder, but still not works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP30 SDK can only be used with defined Honeywell/Intermec devices. On other devices you can use the IP30 via a Bluetooth virtual COM communication and send and receive BRI commands and results (see BRI Programmmers guide).

If that is a supported Windows Mobile 6.x device: Did you download and install the RFID Resource Kit SDK? Did you install the RFID Resource Kit runtime on the Windows Mobile device?

Just copying the DLL file rfidapi32.dll with the same name onto the device will not work, if the DLL references other DLLs or APIs that do not exist. When a DLL is tried to load, it will execute the DLLMain code which can return SUCCESS or an error. If the DLL can not load, your code gets the "can't find ..." error.

The RFID Resource Kit can be downloaded from https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/IF2-Where-can-the-RFID-resource-kit-be-downloaded-from, The IF2 RFID SDK is the same SDK as for the IP30.